# Copy containing a string to other server in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a question
How can I `cat filea.txt` and write to `fileb.txt` with a shell script? `Filea` and `fileb` are different server Linux.

`cat filea.txt >> fileb.txt` in other server

Many thanks!

Comment: `ssh user@remotehost 'cat >> /path/to/file/at/the/remote/host/fileb.txt' < /path/to/local/file/at/localhost/filea.txt`

Comment: To simplify things: `ssh remote_user@remote_host 'cat >> remote_file <' local_file` , Also there are a lot of entries/questions and answer in this forum about your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat filea.txt >> /tmp/fileb.txt
scp /tmp/fileb.txt user@192.168.0.30:~/fileb.txt
```

Just to let you know, `~/` is the home directory of that user. You'd need to replace the user and the ip, ofc.
You can also not paste into the home directory and do a full file path.

scp is really cool, check out its man page.

EDIT: I do see your trouble with the appending.

You can try to `cat filea.txt | ssh user@192.168.0.30 "cat >> fileb.txt"` This works because cat takes from stdin when no file is specified.